# UnicodeDecodeError when filtering then counting a pyspark DataFrame in spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, unicode, pyspark, user-defined-functions, parquet

I have a parquet table that I need to filter based on a UDF and then count the results for further processing. This works interactively, but not in spark-submit.

I've boiled the issue down to the simplest possible example. Here is the interactive code:

```
In [26]: table = table.filter(F.udf(lambda x: True, T.BooleanType())('my_field'))

In [27]: table.count()
Out[27]: 819876
```

However, when I execute the exact same code via spark-submit (yarn cluster mode), I get the following:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "{path}/pyspark/worker.py", line 137, in main
spark_files_dir = utf8_deserializer.loads(infile)
File "{path}/pyspark/serializers.py", line 549, in loads
return s.decode("utf-8") if self.use_unicode else s
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 13: invalid start byte
```

I'm completely baffled by this. Any ideas for what might be going wrong when I execute the above via spark-submit?

python version: 3.6.3

spark version: 2.1.1

**Update**

The following works interactively:

```
In [33]: table.rdd.filter(lambda x: 'my_term' in x.my_field).toDF().count()
Out[33]: 753137
```

But when I try running that through spark-submit, I get the following error:

```
{some_path}/pyspark/serializers.py", line 547, in loads
    s = stream.read(length)
ValueError: read length must be positive or -1
```